# MongoDB: How to convert an object field into an array field of said object

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb

I'm attempting to convert an object field into an array containing that object. Removing the planner object one level and placing it into the planners array:

```
  "planner": {
    "code": "12345",
    "name": "Person"
  } 
->
  "planners": [
    {
      "code": "12345",
      "name": "Person"
    }
  ]
```

Should just be able to create a new array field named planners and remove the old planner object field afterwards. Trying to figure out the syntax of creating this new array field with the existing attributes from another object field.
Was attempting something like this:

```
db.example.find({ }).forEach(function(a) {
    a.planners = [
        {
            "code": a.planner.code,
            "name": a.planner.name
        }
    ]
    db.example.save(a)
})
```

Ending off with the removal

```
db.example.updateMany(
   { },
   { $unset: { planner: "" } }
)
```

This is just returning undefined when executed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB v4.2+, you can just `$set` `planner` with an array wrapping it.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      planner: [
        "$planner"
      ]
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cigXsAE9kXr)